# Where are the native linux methods in openjdk?

Tags: linux, java

I am trying to find native method implementation for linux:

```
private native int socketRead0(FileDescriptor fd,
                                   byte b[], int off, int len,
                                   int timeout)
```

I could not find it in Openjdk source files. I grepped all the files for "socketRead0" but it found only implementations for windows and solaris. Where is it?

Comment: You mean within the Java sources? Maybe it's not needed/supported there. Besides that what do you need that for? You shouldn't call it directly anyways.

Comment: My thread stucks at  this native method invocation. That is why I need to inspect the native code.

Comment: This might help [SocketInputStream.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/java/net/SocketInputStream.c) and bug report [JDK-8075484](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075484)

Comment: This is windows implementation. That's what the problem is - I need linux implementation which could not be found anywhere. I read many bug reports about this issue, but I would like to read (and possiblty attach debugger) to the source.

Answer (score 1):

`socketRead0` implementation for Linux is defined in the Solaris version: [SocketInputStream.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/solaris/native/java/net/SocketInputStream.c).
This file includes [net_util.h](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/native/java/net/net_util.h) which in turn includes [net_util_md.h](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/solaris/native/java/net/net_util_md.h).

[net_util_md.h](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/solaris/native/java/net/net_util_md.h) uses a `#ifdef __linux__` directive to distinguish between Linux and Solaris